# AVAudioPlayer iOS no sound

Tags: objective-c

Seems to be similar questions asked but none of the solutions seem to work for me. Cant for the life of me understand why my code doesnt work so here it is.
I dont get any errors but also get no sound.

```
@interface MainApp ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
-(void)playSoundFX:(NSString*) soundFile;

@end

@implementation MainApp

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Play sound
    [self playSoundFX:@“sound.mp3"];
}

// Play sound
- (void)playSoundFX:(NSString*)soundFile {

    // Setting up path to file url
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* bundleDirectory = (NSString*)[bundle bundlePath];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundleDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:soundFile]];

    // Make an audioPlayer object and play file
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    [audioPlayer setVolume:100.0f];

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    else
        [audioPlayer play];
}

@end

*********vvvvvvvvv Amended Code that works vvvvvvvvv**********

@interface MainApp ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
-(void)playSoundFX:(NSString*) soundFile;

@end

@implementation MainApp

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Play sound
    [self playSoundFX:@“sound.mp3"];
}

// Play sound
- (void)playSoundFX:(NSString*)soundFile {

    // Setting up path to file url
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* bundleDirectory = (NSString*)[bundle bundlePath];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundleDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:soundFile]];

    // Make an audioPlayer object and play file
    NSError *error;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    [self.audioPlayer setVolume:100.0f];

    if (self.audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    else
        [self.audioPlayer play];
}

@end
```

Comment: Ah I found the answer but Im not 100% sure I have the right explanation as to why its happeneing. I declare a instance property of audioPlayer in the interface intending to use it but instead of assigning self.audioPlayer to the alloc init method, it looks like Im creating another audioPlayer inside the method and using that one instead. I presume the instance is going out of scope or deallocating before the sound can play. Would this be an accurate assessment?

Answer (score 0):

I am execute your code on my iPhone. It is work properly.Please Select a device and run your code. I hope it will execute properly with sound.

Comment: Well thats crazy because I am trying to play it on my iPhone6, sound is on and also up in volume on the device, but I still cant hear my sound file. Can somebody else verify JAGATs post?

Answer (score 0):

You got to segregate the functionalities..

Loading audio file in viewDidLoad and play it on play action, some thing like this

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    AVAudioPlayer *_audioPlayer;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Construct URL to sound file
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sound.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    // Create audio player object and initialize with URL to sound
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playSoundTapped:(id)sender
{
    // When button is tapped, play sound
    [_audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Reading you comment was really helpful and interesting but the answer actually lay in the way I was using my (or not using my) audioPlayer property instance. I noticed you were using the underscore so I took another look at how I was declaring mine and they weren't consistent which is why it wasn't working. (Read my comment above) Thanks again for your help.